# Keras deep learning model to android

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm developing a real-time object classification app for android. First I created a deep learning model using "keras" and I already have trained model saved as "model.h5" file. I would like to know how can I use that model in android for image classification.

Comment: it seems that keras models is not designed to support android but I think you can convert the model file to tensorflow model file and then deploy the tensorflow model file to android, this [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3223) can help you do the convertion and this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) can help on how to deploy tensorflow model to android

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cant export Keras directly to Android but you have to save the model

- Configure Tensorflow as your Keras backend.
- Save model wights using `model.save(filepath)` (you already done this)

Then load it with one of the following solutions:

**Solution 1: Import model in Tensflow**

1- Build Tensorflow model

- Build tensorflow model from keras model [use this code](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow/blob/master/keras_to_tensorflow.py) (link updated)

2- Build Android app and call Tensorflow. check this [tutorial](https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html) and this [official demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) from google to learn how to do it.

**Solution 2: Import model in java** 
1- deeplearning4j a java library allow to import keras model: [tutorial link](https://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras) 
2- Use deeplearning4j in Android: it is easy since you are in java world. check [this tutorial](https://deeplearning4j.org/android)

Comment: Is there a preferred solution ? Particularly in terms of performance or size of libraries ? or a commonly accepted best practice ?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to export the **Keras** model to a **Tensorflow** model :

```
def export_model_for_mobile(model_name, input_node_names, output_node_name):
    tf.train.write_graph(K.get_session().graph_def, 'out', \
        model_name + '_graph.pbtxt')

    tf.train.Saver().save(K.get_session(), 'out/' + model_name + '.chkp')

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + model_name + '_graph.pbtxt', None, \
        False, 'out/' + model_name + '.chkp', output_node_name, \
        "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0", \
        'out/frozen_' + model_name + '.pb', True, "")

    input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.Open('out/frozen_' + model_name + '.pb', "rb") as f:
        input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
            input_graph_def, input_node_names, [output_node_name],
            tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('out/tensorflow_lite_' + model_name + '.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

You just need to know the `input_nodes_names` and `output_node_names` of your graph. This will create a new folder with several files. Among them, one starts with **`tensorflow_lite_`**. This is the file you shall move to your Android device.

Then import Tensorflow library on Android and use **`TensorFlowInferenceInterface`** to run your model.

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.5.0'
```

You can check my simple XOR example on Github :

[**https://github.com/OmarAflak/Keras-Android-XOR**](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Keras-Android-XOR)

Answer (score 2):

If you want optimize way  to do classification then i will suggest you  to run inference of your model using armnn android libraries.

You have to follow few steps.
1. Install and setup arm nn libraries in ubuntu. You can take help from below url

https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn/blob/branches/armnn_19_08/BuildGuideAndroidNDK.md

2. Just import your model and do inference. You can  take help from below url

https://developer.arm.com/solutions/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/deploying-a-tensorflow-mnist-model-on-arm-nn/deploying-a-tensorflow-mnist-model-on-arm-nn-single-page

3. After compilation you will get binary which will take input and give you output
4. You can run that binary inside any andriod appication

It is optimize way.