# loading a keras model

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a data set like this

[image]

from this dataset I have built an artificial neural network , that will predict whether a customer will leave the bank or not .

I can predict whether the customer will leave or not like following

```
new_prediction = classifier.predict(sc.transform(np.array([[0.0, 0, 600, 1, 40, 3, 60000, 2, 1, 1, 50000]])))
```

what I want to do is , using that model in android , so that I can input value from android , it will show the result. After searching a lot , I have found tensorflow can do this , for this I need to save model in `.pb` format , I have also saved that .

But now I am clueless , how can load that `pb` file in my device , and predict using tensorflow .

I have added the following gradle dependecy

```
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
```

I am really novice in machine learning stuff , all the example I have seen is related to image classification ,I am really stuck now , any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras deep learning model to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874245/keras-deep-learning-model-to-android)

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817849/tensorflow-wide-and-deep-how-feed-the-csv-file-features-to-input-tensor-of-the