# Loading .h5 model file in Android

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, keras

Good day. I try to load pre built h5 model file for image recognition in Android studio. I've put h5 file into res folder and try to run this

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

String simpleMlp = new ClassPathResource("cnncat2.h5").getFile().getPath();
MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(simpleMlp);
```

but on the line of initiating simpleMlp i got thhis error

```
class path resource [cnncat2.h5] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Could you please help with the correct path? or maybe there is a more easy and straightforward way to read this file?

Comment: have you try to convert the model to tensorflow pb and use tensorflow for inference?

Comment: no, i didnt try it

Comment: try this method because is the most used method.This is the link i used the first time let me know.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874245/keras-deep-learning-model-to-android